# C++ class wrapper and placement new

Tags: c++, wrapper, placement-new

I have a template container class that needs to associate additional information with each instance of the user specified type.

The container specifies a wrapper structure that contains the specified type and the additional information...

```
template<typename T> class Container
{
    ...

    struct Wrapper
    {
        T   mType;
        int mInfo;
    };
}
```

On initialization, the container is populated with dynamically allocated instances of Wrapper (i.e., Wrapper*).  The user can pop() an instance, and the container will return a cast to T*.  The user can push() an instance, which the container will cast back to Wrapper*.

This works fine if the datatype can be default constructed.  However, this is not always the case and I want to let the user provide an allocation function, invoked during initialization, that constructs the datatype however it likes.  It's ok for the container to require a specific signature for the function.

```
template<typename T> template<typename F> void Container<T>::init(F allocator);
```

What I'm struggling with is how to allocate a Wrapper while the function allocates the datatype.  I've thought about using placement new, where the container allocates enough space for Wrapper and passes the address to the function to do a placement new of the datatype.

Is there a cleaner way to go about this?

Comment: it is better to write code, then explain what the class should do. Why create instances, if it is possible to push/pop?

Comment: It's only possible to push/pop objects belonging to the container.  That is, objects decorated with additional information the container needs.  The user sees T*, while the container sees Wrapper*.

Comment: I agree with BЈовић: it's better to write code. However, from what I can understand, you need a constructor in Wrapper that takes your T.

Comment: Why not make `Wrapper::mType` a pointer to `T`?

Comment: Yes, thought about having Wrapper do a copy construction of T, but did not want to require that T is copy constructable.

Comment: Making Wrapper::mType a pointer to T means that on push() the container can't cast T* back to Wrapper*.

Comment: Basically, you want to do the same thing as `std::list` or `std::set` (they are node-based containers that manipulate node structures having `T` as a member). You can look at what the implementation that comes with your compiler does for those - but yes, it's essentially placement new, by way of `allocator::construct`.

Comment: I don't understand, why you want to use a cast. Could you show your pop function?

Comment: If you don't want T be a copy constructible, but want to stay generic, then you can use a technique similar to what boost::multi_index uses: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/creation.html

Comment: Thanks Igor.  This is essentially where I've landed.  The user passes in a construct function (and parameter pack of arguments) that is invoked to perform a placement new on a provided address.  The user is then free to pass whatever arguments they want to the constructor of the type.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need allocation function for this. Instead, you need something like emplace_push from standard containers.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add the parameters used for construction of T as template parameters for Container, and use them to construct a T. To allow dynamic construction of the T objects, the container constructor accepts as parameter a pointer to a function taking as parameter an integer for the creation rank, and the default parameters for T constructor, and returning a tuple of parameter for T constructor (`std::tuple<U...> (*getInitParam)(int rank, U... params)`):

```
template<typename T, typename ...U>
class Container {
    struct Wrapper {
        T mType;
        int mInfo;

        Wrapper(int mInfo, U... params): mType(params...), mInfo(mInfo) {}
    };

    std::stack<Wrapper *> stack;

    int get_mInfo() {
        static int info = 0;

        return info++;
    }
    std::tuple<U...> (*getInitParam)(int rank, U... params);

public:
    T* pop() {
        // should control stack is not empty
        Wrapper *w = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        return &w->mType;
    }
    void push(T* type) {
        char *p = reinterpret_cast<char *>(type);
        p -= offsetof(Wrapper, mType);
        Wrapper *w = reinterpret_cast<Wrapper *>(p);
        // would need to control that *w is a valid Wrapper
        stack.push(w);
    }
    void init(int n, U... params) {
        std::tuple<U...> orig = std::make_tuple(params...);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if (getInitParam != nullptr) {
                std::tie(params...) = orig;
                std::tuple<U...> tparams = (*getInitParam)(i, params...);
                std::tie(params...) = tparams;
            }
            Wrapper *w = new Wrapper(get_mInfo(), params...);
            stack.push(w);
        }
    }
    Container(std::tuple<U...> (*getInitParam)(int rank, U... params) = nullptr)
        : getInitParam(getInitParam) {}
    ~Container() {
        while(! stack.empty()) {
            Wrapper *w = stack.top();
            delete w;
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
};
```

Usage example:

```
std::tuple<size_t, char> doInit(int i, size_t szmin, char c) {
    return std::make_tuple(szmin + i, c);
}

int main() {
    Container<std::string, size_t, char> cont(&doInit);
    cont.init(10, 5, 'x');

    std::string* str0 = cont.pop();
    std::string* str = cont.pop();
    std::cout << *str0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << *str << std::endl;

    *str0 = "bar";

    cont.push(str0);
    cont.push(str);

    str0 = cont.pop();
    str = cont.pop();

    std::cout << *str << std::endl;
    cont.push(str);
    cont.push(str0);
    return 0;
}
```

This correctly outputs:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
bar
```

There is still to implement mInfo usage, but it should be a start point...

Comment: Yes, this works if the constructor arguments for T are static.  Consider the simple case where every instance of T requires a unique ID as part of its constructor.  This is why I wanted the user to be able to pass in a sort of allocator.

Comment: @user1715664: I think I can meet that requirement with an optional function that computes the parameters used for T object construction. See edited post.